# Explain different ways of starting VLC media player from the command line in Linux

Tags: vlc

What are the different ways of starting VLC media player from the command line in Linux?

It is maddeningly difficult to find any information about this. Here is what I've discovered so far:

vlc - start VLC media player
cvlc - start VLC media player without the interface
qvlc - start the Qt version of VLC media player

What about the others:

svlc - 
rvlc - 
nvlc -

Comment: In Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/nvlc` contains the instruction `vlc -I ncurses`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the aliases in [Makefile.am](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/Makefile.am#L118).

- `svlc` - enables skins
- `rvlc` - enables the remote control interface
- `nvlc` - enables `ncurses`